# Thoughts on Digital Performer?

Tags: sound-design, motu, daw, software

I was wondering what everyone's opinion was on MOTU's Digital Performer? I know some people have probably never heard of this program, but at Evergreen State College where I took some audio courses this program was our bible. I've actually fallen quite in love with this programs interface and find that it usually can fit all of my audio needs (mostly). Don't get me wrong I'm still ProTools through and through, but this program has definitely gotten a special place in my heart. Any thoughts on it fellow sound designers? :)

Cheers,
Michael Brennan

Answer (score 2):

I used performer for years before eventually switching to logic, and the reason I switched was absolutely no fault of performer's. That program's awesome. I didn't love the stock plugs as much, but i never really used them enough to complain, and there are some better ones now. The last version I used was 7, and it was excellent. Also, the Motunation.com board is a terrific and active community, and I still post on their frequently. This is all coming from a non-pro-tools person, so I don't know what's fitting your needs. In fact, I only ever really used it for music, but it was great for that.

Comment: I had the same experience as Dave. Logic IMO was a better interface and far more unified. DP felt like I was managing too many windows at once. However, if you know it well, it's every bit as capable, just different - I just found that Logic's workflow better mapped to my own mental model. This is why different DAWs exist: Everyone's needs are super different!

Answer (score 0):

Not the cheapest, used to be mac-only (and MOTU didn't seem to focus too much on their audio interface range's Windows drivers either), not many users so project file swapping can be a problem, not sure how active the development is because it's not so popular.

As a program, well, it's a tool as capable as pretty much any other DAW. Not having support for VSTs on mac is one considerable minus though. Although if you only wish to use AUs, then it of course doesn't matter.